# Using MahApps Metro theme VS2013

Tags: c#, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to do the Getting Started instructions here: http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/guides/quick-start.html.

I've gotten the latest pre-release (tried with stable too), I'm not getting the same window the guide is producing. I'm getting a transparent window and titlebar, so it looks like a floating titlebar, and minimize, maximize and close buttons.

When I add the styling I get a white background with a blue titlebar, but no shadow. Am I doing something wrong here or has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks.

**EDIT: here's the XAML**

**Main Window**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Metro.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="1600">
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Metro.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

As I mentioned, I followed the getting started instructions, I copy and pasted the exact same code, and got a different result.

Comment: what os you are running ?

Comment: Windows 8, but optimistically need it to run on Vista and 7 as well.

Comment: How you tried it? post your XAML. It is working fine for me, Win 8, VS2012 here.

Comment: The background color isn't so important anymore, although as a final product I'd like to offer users the ability to change color schemes. At the very least I'd like to have the drop shadow working though.

Answer (score 45):

**EDIT**
The [quick start](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html) guide and the `MetroWindow` [help](http://mahapps.com/controls/metro-window.html) now updated (04.09.2014).

The screenhots/examples at the quickstart are not quite updated.

You can have a border

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      Title="MainWindow"
                      Height="200"
                      Width="600"

                      BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="1"

                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

[image]

or a glow border

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      Title="MainWindow"
                      Height="200"
                      Width="600"

                      GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"

                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

[image]

or a drop shadow

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      xmlns:behaviours="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
                      Title="MainWindow"
                      Height="200"
                      Width="600"
                      ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
                      WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviours:BorderlessWindowBehavior AllowsTransparency="False"
                                         EnableDWMDropShadow="True" />
    <behaviours:WindowsSettingBehaviour />
    <behaviours:GlowWindowBehavior />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

**Update**

`EnableDWMDropShadow` has been moved to `MetroWindow` in version 0.13 alpha (latest version)

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Simple.Demo.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      xmlns:behaviours="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
                      Title="MainWindow"
                      Height="200"
                      Width="600"

                      EnableDWMDropShadow="True"
                      ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"

                      WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

</controls:MetroWindow>
```

[image]

hope that helps

Comment: I'm not seeing the drop shadow, even when I set EnableDWMDropShadow to true. I'm running on Windows 8.1, don't know if it matters. EDIT: actually the drop shadow is there, but only when the window is focused...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque "actually the drop shadow is there, but only when the window is focused..." i think that's the windows behavior, or not?

Comment: I don't know, but it looks weird, because the window appears to have no border at all, unless I set the BorderThickness to 1, but then it shows a dark border instead of the shadow. If I force the BorderBrush to something lighter, then it continues to show up when the drop shadow is visible.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque you can try set `BorderBrush` and  `NonActiveBorderBrush` to get what you want (>= 0.13)

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that property... it's not perfect, but it's a good workaround.

Comment: `EnableDWMDropShadow` is Obsolete in the latest version